# TypeORM: How to set ForeignKey explicitly without having property for loading relations?

Tags: foreign-keys, typeorm, typescript-decorator

I don't want to create a property for loading relation into it (as shown in all the examples). The only thing I need is to have an *explicit foreign key property* so that the *migration* will be able to create appropriate constraints for it in the database. The closest decorator to the one I need is [@RelationId](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/decorator-reference.md#relationid) but it still requires the presence of a property of the relational class.

For clarity let's take the example from the documentation:

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
    @ManyToOne(type => Category)
    category: Category;

    @RelationId((post: Post) => post.category) // it still requires the presence of the `category` proeprty
    categoryId: number;

}
```

I don't need the `category` property here. I want to have the `categoryId` property and mark it as *foreign key* to `Category.Id`. It should look like this:

```
@Entity()
export class Post {

    @ForeignKey((category: Category) => category.Id) // it's a foreign key to Category.Id
    categoryId: number;

}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Hey did you figure a way around this?

Comment: Sorry, man, I've changed my tech stack a year ago. I believe I didn't find a way around at the time.

Comment: Ye i figured it out based on charles solution it works.

Answer (score 16):

"I need is to have an explicit foreign key property"...

No, you could not. TypeOrm will automatically create foreign key property when you use @ManyToOne decorator. Just combine @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn decorators together like this:

```
@ManyToOne(type => Category)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'custom_field_name_if_you_want' })
category: Category;
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you can create and write your own migration and use it like this :

```
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
        name: "question",
        columns: [
            {
                name: "id",
                type: "int",
                isPrimary: true
            },
            {
                name: "name",
                type: "varchar",
            }
        ]
    }), true);

    await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
        name: "answer",
        columns: [
            {
                name: "id",
                type: "int",
                isPrimary: true
            },
            {
                name: "name",
                type: "varchar",
            },
            {
                name: "questionId",
                isUnique: connection.driver instanceof CockroachDriver, // CockroachDB requires UNIQUE constraints on referenced columns
                type: "int",
            }
        ]
    }), true);

    // clear sqls in memory to avoid removing tables when down queries executed.
    queryRunner.clearSqlMemory();

    const foreignKey = new TableForeignKey({
        columnNames: ["questionId"],
        referencedColumnNames: ["id"],
        referencedTableName: "question",
        onDelete: "CASCADE"
    });
    await queryRunner.createForeignKey("answer", foreignKey);
```

This code snippet is extracted from the [functional test](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/query-runner/create-foreign-key.ts) of type orm and you can use it to create your own constraint on the database I think.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually possible to do so:

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
    // this will add categoryId
    @ManyToOne(type => Category)
    category: Category;

    // and you can use this for accessing post.categoryId
    // only column you mark with @Column decorator will be mapped to a database column 
    // Ref: https://typeorm.io/#/entities
    categoryId: number;

}
```

The added `categoryId` won't be mapped to column and will then be use for setting explicitly the id or for accessing its value as in:

```
 post.categoryId = 1;
 // or 
 const id = post.categoryId
```

Comment: I think the categoryId needs the Column Decorator =>  @Column({ nullable: false }) https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/156#issuecomment-269579837

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem recently.
I still use the Entity but only with the primary key value of the referenced entity.

i.e. I do not query the database for the referenced entity.

Suppose your category entity looks like this:

```
@Entity()
export class Category{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    // ... other stuff
}
```

Now using your codes as example.
Dircely assigning relation using a foreign key value would be like.

```
// You wish to assign category #12 to a certain post
post.category = { id: 12 } as Category
```

Answer (score -1):

Check with these two places Auth `module(JwtModule.register())` and JWT `strategy(super({...}))`. Make sure you have `secret` and `secretOrKey` is set to the same key. In my case `secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY` and  `secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY`.

Comment: Hi @Sunny Tare, remember to use block code format to make your code easier to read in your answer